# Xamarin Android - Criar uma linha por onde o dedo passar

Tags: android, xamarin, canvas, touch

Olá, gostaria de criar uma reta ou retangulo, por onde meu dedo passar.
Na verdade não precisa ser exatamente por onde passar,
mas em cima de cada button que eu passar o dedo ele vai aumentando o retangulo,
como se fosse uma seleção de uma palavra em um "caça-palavras".
Tenho um `GridLayout` de 15x15 e um `button` dentro de cada célula.

[image: Imagem com Exemplo]

Tentei colocar no onTouch de cada botão como abaixo mas não deu.

```
    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                _viewX = e.GetX();
                _viewY = e.GetY();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                var left = (int)(e.RawX - _viewX);
                var right = (int)(left + v.Width);

                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                Canvas c = new Canvas();
                c.DrawRect(new Rect((int)_viewX, (int)_viewY, (int)_viewX + 200, (int)_viewY + 200), new Paint() { Color = Color.Red });

                ((GirdLayout)v.Parent).Draw(c);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```